# i tried to Run flutter i got this :Assertion failed:

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-bottomnavigation

[image]

I tried to Run flutter and i got this error: Another exception was thrown: Assertion failed:
file:///home/moi/snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/bottom_navigation_bar.dart:189:9

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide `label` on your `BottomNavigationBarItem`.

You can just empty string like

```dart
 BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.abc), label: ""),
```

If you like to hide labels, do like this

```dart
bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
  showSelectedLabels: false,// this
  showUnselectedLabels: false,// this
  items: [
    BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.abc), label: ""),
    BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.abc), label: ""),
  ],
),
```

Comment: Glad to help, you can check more about  [BottomNavigationBar](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/BottomNavigationBar-class.html)    [someone-answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers#:~:text=To%20mark%20an%20answer%20as,the%20answer%2C%20at%20any%20time.)